# change pdfcomment text box color and border in latex

Tags: pdftex, pdfcomment

I want to change the textbox colour from ugly yellow to something else. Does anyone know how to do it? And is it possible to get rid of the black border lines?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[author={},subject={test},color=green!25]{Commented text}{Comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems your example already solves the textbox colour part your question, by using `color=green!25`. And, what do you mean by saying "black border lines"? Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: I meant the color of the comment box. color=green!25 changes the color of the text that is being commented. I use Preview of mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OP's example, I cannot see the yellow comment box. I use Preview 11.0 and latest Adobe Acrobat Reader on macOS 10.15.2. (Acrobat Reader crashes when I click "About" to check its version, so I cannot provide the exact version number.)

[image: open with Preview]

[image: open with Adobe Acrobat Reader]

My latex package version info (You can get yours by adding `\listfiles` in the preamble, run pdflatex, and then find version info from log file.):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
pdfcomment.sty    2018/11/01 pdfcomment.sty v2.4a - Josef Kleber (C) 2008-2012,
 2015-2016, 2018
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
datetime2.sty    2019/11/11 v1.5.5 (NLCT) date and time formats
tracklang.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4 (NLCT) Track Languages
tracklang.tex    2019/11/30 v1.4 (NLCT) Track Languages Generic Code
zref-savepos.sty    2019/11/29 v2.28 Module savepos for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2019/11/29 v2.28 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   iftex.sty    2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 soulpos.sty    2012/02/25 v1.1 Fancy underlining
hyperref.sty    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   puenc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-02-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
soulutf8.sty    2019/12/15 v1.2 Permit use of UTF-8 characters in soul (HO)
    soul.sty    2003/11/17 v2.4 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
pdfcomment.out
pdfcomment.out
supp-pdf.mkii
se-pdfdoc.def    2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: PDFDocEncoding
pdfcomment.upa
 ***********
```

Comment: It seems that the default pdf viewer color is used. [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) shows all note boxes in blue.